# HTML wont read both my scipt tags for JavaScript

Tags: html

For some reason my main page only reads the top script tag but wont read the one underneath it. I have 2 - 1 does an expand function and the other 1 is a javaplugin that tilts some wording on scroll.

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>  
<script src="js/demo/jquery.tiltedpage-scroll.js"></script>
```

This is what I have pasted at the bottom of my html file before the body tag. It only reads the top one but the bottom then doesn't work. What am i missing?

Comment: If those two script tags are in the same location in the markup, and the `src`s are correct, they should both load. Why do you think the script is not being loaded, is it just not working as expected? do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Make sure to put first script tag (`script.js` one) at the end of body tag

Comment: what @TechySharnav said. switch the order. jquery stuff first.